# Angular getting cartSize with async pipe not working

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to get the size of my cart using the async pipe:

```
<h1>
  {{cartSize$ | async}}
</h1>
```

The component where the observable is defined is:

```
export class ProductsComponent {
  cart$: Observable<Product[]>;
  cartSize$: Observable<number>;
  products: Product[] = [];
  constructor(
    private walmartService: WalmartService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    this.cart$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCart));
    this.cartSize$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCartSize));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.walmartService
      .getProducts()
      .subscribe((products) => (this.products = products));
  }
  addOne(product: Product): void {
    this.store.dispatch(addOneItem({ payload: product }));
  }

  removeOne(product: Product): void {
    this.store.dispatch(removeOneItem({ payload: product }));
  }

  removeAll(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(removeAll());
  }

  removeItem(product: Product): void {
    this.store.dispatch(removeItem({ payload: product }));
  }
}
```

and the relevant reducer info like so:

```
export interface AppState {
  cart: CartState;
}

export interface CartState {
  cart: Product[];
  cartSize: number;
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  cart: {
    cart: [],
    cartSize: 10,
  },
};

export const selectCartState = (state: AppState) => state.cart;
export const selectCartSize = createSelector(
  selectCartState,
  (state: CartState) => state.cartSize
);
export const selectCart = createSelector(
  selectCartState,
  (state: CartState) => state.cart
);
```

However, nothing is showing on the page and I'm not sure why. Any idea why?

Initially, I didn't even want to make the cartSize prop in the store because each Product has a count and I could simply reduce it from the total cart of products. But then I ran into some issues with piping and reducing the cart observable and decided to go this route. If there's a better way to get the cart size especially since each product has a count prop, please let me know!

Comment: Maybe try to initialize it directly on declaration instead of in the constructor. Also, I would not use a separate `cartSize` property. Instead you can use the pipe operator `scan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.store.select` not `.pipe`.

And here is how you can get rid of the separate count varialble:

```js
readonly cartSize$ = this.store.select(selectCart()).pipe(
  map((products: Product[]) => {
    return products.reduce((total: number, { quantity }: Product) => total + quantity, 0);
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

I assume the "count"-variable of `Product` is called `quantity`, but you can change it if needed.

I use `shareReplay(1)` to make it a hot observable, so when you subscribe to it multiple times, it won't run each time. In this case it is not necessary, since you only subscribe to it once (using `async` pipe), but I think it is always a good idea to use hot observables when writing declarative.